# ¿Cómo obtener fecha especifica entre un rango de fechas? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datetime, date, datepicker

Tengo dos `DateTimePicker` para obtener un rango de fechas, y un `GroupBox` que contiene `CheckBoxs` para identificar los días de la semana.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Pretendo Recorrer el rango de fechas y solo realizar la operación deseada cuando la fecha del rango pertenezca a las opciones de los `CheckBox` seleccionados, como se muestra en mi imagen, del rango de fecha seleccionado solo deseo ejecutar una acción cuando la fecha del rango sea **`Lunes`, `Miércoles`, `Viernes` o los dias que seleccione el usuario**.

Algo como esto:

```
DateTime fecha_inicio = DateTime.Parse(fecha_desde.Value.ToString()); 
DateTime fecha_fin = DateTime.Parse(fecha_hasta.Value.ToString()); 

for (DateTime fecha = fecha_inicio; fecha <= fecha_fin; fecha = fecha.AddDays(1))
{
     //Aqui preguntar si la fecha pertenece a uno de los dias seleccionados 
     //if(fecha ...)
     //{
          //Ejecutar la acción.....
     //}
}
```

Con esto poder identificar los `CheckBox` **Checked == True**:

```
foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
{
      if (control is CheckBox)
          if (( (CheckBox)control ).Checked && ( (CheckBox)control ).Text != "Seleccionar Todos")
            //Asignar algun valor para identificar cada dia...
}
```

**¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?**

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2010, C# & .NET Netframework 4.

Comment: Y tu codigo tiene algun error? Que exactamente no te funciona con lo que tienes?

Comment: Dentro del ciclo `For` no se como preguntar si la fecha pertenece a uno de los `CheckBox` seleccionados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la propiedad `Tag` de cada `Checkbox`, le asignale el numero del dia correspondiente al `Checkbox`. Por ejemplo el domingo tendrá el valor de 0, el lunes tendrá el valor 1, martes el valor de 2 y etc., etc hasta llegar al sabado que es 6. Esto lo puedes asignar, buscando dando clic derecho sobre el Checkbox->Propiedades y buscas por `Tag`.

Luego crea un evento change que se ejecutara cuando se seleccione/desseleccione el checkbox. **Le asignaras el mismo metodo a todos los checkbox**.  Este lo que hara es que si selecionas un checkbox, guardaras el valor del `Tag` que contiene el dia en una lista, si ya existe en la lista, lo eliminas.

```
List<int> diasSeleccionados = new List<int>();
public void diaSeleccionado_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e){

    var dia = Convert.ToInt32((sender as Checkbox).Tag);

    // verificamos si existe el dia en checkbox
    if(diasSeleccionados.Contains(dia))
    {
        diasSeleccionados.Remove(dia);
    }
    else{
        // lo agregamos ya que no fue seleccionado
        diasSeleccionados.Add(dia);
    }
}
```

Entonces como ya sabes cuales dias fueron selecionado, solo tendiras que buscar si el dia de la fecha que esta en el checkbox esta presente en la lista `diasSeleccionados`:

```
DateTime fecha_inicio = DateTime.Parse(fecha_desde.Value.ToString()); 
DateTime fecha_fin = DateTime.Parse(fecha_hasta.Value.ToString()); 

for (DateTime fecha = fecha_inicio; fecha <= fecha_fin; fecha = fecha.AddDays(1))
{
     // verificamos el dia esta en el array
     if(diasSeleccionados.Contains((int)fecha.DayOfWeek))
     {
        // el dia esta seleccionado
     }
}
```

Nota: Los valores que le son asignados a los tag, representa los valores del Enum [`DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Esta linea: `if (diasSeleccionados.Contains(checkbox))` me parece que debe ser: `if (diasSeleccionados.Contains(dia))`

Comment: Si, tienes razon. Ya edite la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y aporte.

Answer (score 1):

Para comparar 2 fechas tienes que utilizar el método compareTo de la clase DateTime.

Aquí puedes ver su documentación: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya(v=vs.110).aspx

En tu caso yo haría algo así:

```
DateTime fecha_inicio = DateTime.Parse(fecha_desde.Value.ToString()); 
DateTime fecha_fin = DateTime.Parse(fecha_hasta.Value.ToString()); 

DateTime fAux = fecha_inicio;

while(fAux.compareTo(fecha_fin)==-1)  //Quiere decir que fecha es menor que fecha_fin
{
    //Ahora hacemos lo que haga falta con la fecha
    ...
    fecha.AddDays(1); //Incrementamos en 1 los días
}
```

Para ver que día de la semana es se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
int dia = fAux.getDayOfWeek()
```

Este método te devuelve un entero entre 0 y 6 que indica el día de la semana que es( Si no me equivoco, es posible que vaya de 1 a 7).

Teniendo el número de día, debería ser fácil comparar con los valores de los checkbox.

Comment: **La validación de comparar la fecha lo hago en el evento `Validating` del control `DateTimePicker`** al momento del usuario seleccionar el rango, valido que la fecha final no sea menor que la de inicio.

Comment: perfecto, pues ahora con el método getDayOfWeek solo te queda comparar con los CheckBox que has seleccionado.

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar: `System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");`, luego debes setear los nombres correctos a los checkboxy validar si son los mismo valores. Aquí un ejemplo según tu código.

```
//Recorrido de tu rango de fechas
for (DateTime fecha = fecha_inicio; fecha <= fecha_fin; fecha = fecha.AddDays(1))
{
   //Obteniendo los valores checkeados
   foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
   {
      if (control is CheckBox){
          if (( (CheckBox)control ).Checked && ( (CheckBox)control ).Text != "Seleccionar Todos")
          {

           //Validación
if(fecha.ToString("dddd") == control.Text){
//Realizar tu lógica correspondiente
}
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, también es buena propuesta.